# Ensamblador ¿Por que se está imprimiendo este dato al revés?

Tags: base64, ensamblador, nasm, x86, assembly

soy nuevo en ensamblador y estoy experimentando algunas cosas con el fin de aprender.  Me gustaría averiguar por qué el dato se imprime al revés.
Comentaré el código usando las barras diagonales para que la máquina entienda que es un comentario aunque no sea propio de ensamblador. Así indicaré los registros y alguna que otra duda por el camino.
Estoy ensamblando con NASM en un Intel(i3) de 64 bits en sistema operativo Linux.
Gracias de antemano.

```
section .bss
 aux resb 1 //En este punto no sé por qué, para este código, no varía si modifico resb por resw o resd por ejemplo
section .text
 global CMAIN
CMAIN:
xor eax, eax
mov ah, "h" // rax = (h)1101000-00000000
mov al, "i" //rax  (hi)1101000-01101001
mov [aux], ax
//imprimir
mov rax, 1
mov rdi, 1
mov rsi, aux 
mov rdx, 2
syscall
xor rax, rax
ret
```

El resultado es este **"ih"**, es decir, **al revés** pues los 8 bits de mayor peso corresponden a la "h" y los de menos peso a la "i". Gracias de nuevo.

Comment: No estoy seguro si es así, pero creo que primero se escanean los 8 bits inferiores y luego los superiores, entonces por eso se imprime primero la 'i' y luego la 'h'.